# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: pyqgis

When I try to load qgis within an external Python instance, I get the following error:

```
>>> from PyQt4.QtCore import *
>>> from PyQt4.QtGui import *
>>> import qgis
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "E:\QGIS\apps\qgis\python\qgis\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from qgis.core import QgsFeature, QgsGeometry
  File "E:\QGIS\apps\qgis\python\qgis\core\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from qgis._core import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

QGIS version: 2.16.1.

Python in QGIS:

```
>>> print(sys.version)
2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Python installation:

```
>>> print(sys.version)
2.7.12 (v2.7.12:d33e0cf91556, Jun 27 2016, 15:24:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Paths in Python installation:

```
>>> print(sys.path)
['', 'E:\\QGIS\\apps\\qgis\\python', ...
```

Additionally the following paths are set in the environment of Windows:

```
E:\QGIS\apps\qgis\python;E:\QGIS\apps\qgis\bin;
```

Any idea how to fix this? Or how shall I setup my system to be able to access QGIS "interactively" from external Python IDEs ?

Answer (score 1):

For those still trying to make this work, here is my working configuration (with QGIS 2.14 LTR) to launch PyCharm with a fully working QGIS environment.

```
@echo off
call "C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.14\bin\o4w_env.bat"
@echo off
path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-ltr\bin;%PATH%
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT:\=/%/apps/qgis-ltr
set GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES
rem Set VSI cache to be used as buffer, see #6448
set VSI_CACHE=TRUE
set VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000
set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-ltr\qtplugins;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qt4\plugins
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.14\apps\qgis-ltr\python;C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.14\apps\qgis-ltr\python\plugins
set PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\\apps\\qgis-ltr\\bin;%PATH%
SET PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python27
@"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.2.2\bin\pycharm.exe"
```

Note that with the above configuration (saved as a .bat file to launch pycharm) it still misses something in the IDE to get syntax completion for the QGIS API.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is to navigate to and choose your QGIS python as the *existing interpreter* to use for your project as explained in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm-edu/configuring-python-interpreter-for-a-project.html and shown below.

[image]

Hacking your installations to use modules from one python within a different interpreter will bite you sooner or later. The best practice is to install the packages you need in one python installation and use that python in your project. Kudos to the PyCharm developers for promoting best practices for Python.